# Source of John Deere line of children bicycle tires?

Tags: tire, children

My son's bike is 12 inch children bike with the John Deere tractor theme to it.  Aside from the paint, this line of kids bikes have some rather beefy, large square knobby tires.  As with any children's bike, the back tire needs replaced (due to rider and coaster brake).  I'm having trouble sourcing these tires and the only information the side wall is given me is "Yida".  Here is a amazon link to the 16 inch version of this bike which has the same kind of tires on it:

[http://www.amazon.com/ERTL-John-Deere-Heavy-Bicycle/dp/B0007WOHZA/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1380045299&sr=8-3&keywords=16+inch+john+deere+bike](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007WOHZA)

While I replaced the tires with standard off the shelf tires, I'm looking for some more information about the company and or the tire itself.

Comment: That looks like a standard kid's bike tire.  I don't know that there would be anything special about the Deere version other than the specific tread pattern.  You might have trouble finding the specific size, but the sizing is fairly standard and a bike shop should be able to order based on the size stamped on the tire.

Comment: It is the tread pattern that is special about these tires and really adds to the over all character of the bike.  The tire size is standard, and I have replaced it with the common knobby tire pattern that is sold on everything and everywhere.

Comment: Very likely the tread design is (relatively) unique.  You might try contacting John Deere directly, or, for a wild shot, try your local Harley dealer, as they sometimes sell bikes of similar design (but obviously different paint scheme).

Comment: I saw another bike as a Jeep line.  I found a vender on amazon but only for the 16in not the 12in.  It might be discontinued.

Comment: Any info about the tire maker?

Comment: There are at least 10 different Chinese tire companies with Yida in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Very inexpensive rebranded bike with very inexpensive tires which you can't source individually. Nothing wrong with that given that it's a child's bike, but that is the situation. Your chances of finding that exact tire are slim, and there's no really compelling reason for you to hunt it down anyway.

The product you can get off the shelf is going to be at least as good and likely better. There's no issue with mixing and matching different tread patterns front and rear beyond aesthetics.

Comment: This is the answer I knew about when I asked the question, which I'm ok with, so I'll +1 it.  I figured I would caste the question out there and see what I reeled in.